# UIScrollView not canceling UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that is filled with photo thumbnail buttons (much like the photos app). The buttons are custom and implement the same behavior as `UIButton` using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

What I would like to happen is if the user goes to scroll the `UITableView`, that if their touch lands on one of my buttons as they begin to scroll, I'd like for my button to cancel the touch. I've tried implementing in the `UITableView`:

```
self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
self.canCancelContentTouches = YES;

- (BOOL) touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}
```

Doesn't work. I've tried doing:

```
[self.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.thumbnailButtonView.longPressGestureRecognizer];
```

Doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea of how to implement this behavior? Is is possible to have the UIScrollView cancel the UILongPressGestureRecognizer touches?

Comment: Why you need UILongPressGestureRecognizer on Button as they already support the touchUpInside?

Comment: @retro - to implement some of the button highlight behavior from iOS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out that the way to approach this is not by trying to have the `UIScrollView`
cancel the touches of the button, but have to change the behavior of the button.

I created my button to behave exactly like a `UIButton`, so if you push down on it, it highlights. Then if you drag your finger while it's still pushed down, and lift up while still in the button frame, it will trigger the button action. I had to make it so that if you drag after pushing down, it removes the button highlight, and thus prevents the button action from being triggered if the user lifts their finger in the button area.

Code below is actually how to implement a button in this fashion using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (void) longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint touchedPoint = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

    if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
        {
            [self addHighlights];
        }
        else
        {
            [self removeHighlights];
        }
    }
    else if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
            if (self.highlightView.superview)
    {
        [self removeHighlights];
    }
    }
    else if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (self.highlightView.superview)
        {
            [self removeHighlights];

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
            {
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:)])
                {
                    [self.delegate buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:self];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void) addHighlights
{
    [self addSubview:self.highlightView];
}

- (void) removeHighlights
{
    [self.highlightView removeFromSuperview];
}
```